# Resizable handles not working if created runtime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

Trying to achieve a simple functionality of re sizing inner element through outer element.

JQuery resizable handles not working if element and custom handles are created through js. Below is the js code.

```
var resizable_handles_html = '[div sructure]'; //editor ommiting codes :)

$(function(){
  $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("[tried to put div here]")   //editor ommiting codes :)
      .css({
        'background':'white',
        'width':'100px',
        'height':'100px',
        'border':'dotted 1px #000',
        'position':'relative'
      })
      .append(resizable_handles_html)
      .draggable()
      //.resizable({handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw"})
      .resizable({
        handles: {
          'nw': '.nwgrip',
          'ne': '.negrip',
          'sw': '.swgrip',
          'se': '.segrip',
          'n': '.ngrip',
          'e': '.egrip',
          's': '.sgrip',
          'w': '.wgrip'
        }
      })
      .append(
        $("[tried to put div here]")   //editor ommiting codes :)
          .attr({
            id:'text',
            contenteditable:'true'
          })
          .css({
            'background':'blue',
            'width':'auto',
            'height':'auto',
            'border':'dotted 1px #000',
            '-moz-border-radius': '15px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '15px',
            'border-radius': '15px',
            '-khtml-border-radius': '15px'
          })
      )
      .appendTo('body');
  });
})
```

Tried to paste contents of variable 'resizable_handles_html', but showing only quotes.

Now element is getting created but throwing an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of
>   undefined" on click of that element."

It is not happening for draggable thats for sure. Created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keshabdey/7m8GF/5/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for adding the blockquotes @m59

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle, seems to work:

fixed markup, handles had multiple class attributes

```
var resizable_handles_html = '<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw nwgrip">    </div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne negrip"></div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw swgrip"></div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se segrip"></div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n ngrip"></div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s sgrip"></div>'
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e egrip"></div>'+
'<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w wgrip"></div>';
```

used default .resizable constructor as well

http://jsfiddle.net/7m8GF/8/